# A very simple SSRS 2008 question

Tags: reporting-services

How can I get custom bullets on my report. Also the default bullet for level 1 is round. How do I change the default to a square or to a different shape. The following is the RDL snippet:

```
<ListStyle>Bulleted</ListStyle>
<ListLevel>1</ListLevel>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across this on MSDN. Windings font is being used!

[How do a make a bulleted list](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/da6a19c6-eb6a-488c-85e2-226a93b1dda9/)

Answer (score 1):

You could try css style values (list-style-type: square). Though I have to admit I'm not sure if that can be done in the rdl or inline HTML in SSRS 2008.